# Sentence structure with trotzdem

Tags: english-to-german, sentence-structure, standard-german

Is it necessary to have a verb after "nach" or we can begin the next clause of the sentence?

> In my opinion, nevertheless e-books are more environmental friendly than paper books.

My sentence:

> Meiner Meinung nach, trotzdem sind E-Books umweltfreundlicher als Papier.

Translator:

> ebooks sind meiner Meinung nach trotzdem besser als Papier

Comment: The verb has to be in second position, “meiner Meinung nach” counts as one unit regarding this, “trotzdem” as another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Let's build the correct German sentence step by step:

- Plain sentence:

  > E-Books sind umweltfreundlicher als Papierbücher.
  > <sup>E-books are more environmentally friendly than paper books.</sup>
- With an additional adverb:

  > E-Books sind **trotzdem** umweltfreundlicher als Papierbücher.
  > <sup>E-books are **nevertheless** more environmentally friendly than paper books.</sup>
- Without this adverb but with a fixed phrase that as a whole behaves like an adverb:

  > E-Books sind **meiner Meinung nach** umweltfreundlicher als Papierbücher.
  > <sup>E-books are more environmentally friendly than paper books **in my opinion.**</sup>
- Now both: adverb and adverbial phrase:

  > E-Books sind **meiner Meinung nach trotzdem** umweltfreundlicher als Papierbücher.
  > <sup>E-books are **nevertheless** more environmentally friendly than paper books, **in my opinion.**</sup>
- In German you can have any part of speech on position 1, so why not this adverbial phrase? You just need to move the subject to position 3 instead. This is the translation you were searching for:

  > **Meiner Meinung nach** sind E-Books **trotzdem** umweltfreundlicher als Papierbücher.
  > <sup>**In my opinion, nevertheless,** e-books are more environmentally friendly than paper books.</sup>

---

You asked if it is necessary to have a verb after *"nach".*

1. This doesn't matter in this case, because *"meiner Meinung nach"* is a fixed phrase, that as a whole behaves like one word (like an adverb), so it doesn't matter from which components this phrase is made.
2. The answer to your question is: No. The word *"nach"* is a preposition and in fact it is normally impossible to have a verb after a preposition. If you have a sentence where you have a verb after a preposition, then this sentence probably is wrong. This is only possible if *"nach"* is used as a postposition, but this happens only in fixed phrases like *"meiner Meinung nach"* as far as I know.

---

Also note:

In German it's neither *"ebook"* nor *"Ebook"* (both are wrong, they do not exist in German language) but only *"E-Book".* In English you can choose between *"ebook"* and *"e-book"* where *"e-book"* is the recommended version. The versions *"Ebook"* and *"E-book"* are both wrong in English.<sup>1</sup>

Never trust a translator who writes a German noun with a lowercase initial letter!

Another error: *"Better"* is not the correct translation for *"umweltfreundlicher"!* And *"paper books"* are not *"Papier"* but *"Papierbücher"* or *"Papier-Bücher"* in German.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Also: Electronic mail is in German not *"Email"* but *"E-Mail"* (pronunciation [ˈiːmeɪ̯l]). The word *"Email"* (pronunciation [eˈmaɪ̯] or [eˈmaɪ̯l]) exists in German, but it is *"enamel"* in English. This is a thin layer of glass on a metal surface.</sub>

Comment: Ich vermute mit "Papierbücher" sind "gedruckte Bücher" gemeint, der Begriff steht nicht im Duden oder DWDS ?

Comment: @a_donda: Die Gitarrensaite und die Windelbox stehen auch weder im Duden noch im DWDS. Das bedeutet aber nicht, dass es diese Wörter nicht gäbe. Entscheidend ist der tatsächliche Gebrauch durch Muttersprachler. [Quelle1](https://www.co2online.de/service/klima-orakel/beitrag/e-book-oder-papierbuch-was-ist-umweltfreundlicher-3319/), [Quelle2](https://www.wiwo.de/technologie/green/frage-der-woche-e-book-oder-papierbuch-was-ist-umweltfreundlicher/13546354.html), [Quelle3](https://www.verbraucherservice-bayern.de/themen/umwelt/e-books-umweltfreundliche-alternative-zum-papierbuch)

Comment: Papierbücher, Gitarrensaite und Windelbox sind ad-hoc Kreationen. Wenn du nur den Gebrauch als Richtlinie für eine Sprache ansiehst, dann kannst du alle Regeln über Bord werfen, denn man wird wohl jede sprachliche Abwegigkeit irgendwo finden. Ich finde wir sollten in Namen der Qualität auf solche Vereinfachungen verzichten um nicht unnötig zu verwirren und abzulenken.

Comment: @a_donda: Was sonst als den tatsächlichen Gebrauch möchtest du denn gerne als endgültige und ultimative Richtlinie ansehen? Es gibt keine Behörde, kein Gericht oder sonst eine normative Institution, die darüber entscheiden könnte, was richtig oder falsch ist. So etwas gibt es nur für die Rechtschreibung (das ist der [Rechtschreibrat](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com)). Rechtschreibung ist aber nur eine Technik, um Sprache in Schrift umzuwandeln. Die Rechtschreibung macht genau gar keine Aussagen darüber, wie gesprochene Sprache beschaffen sein soll. ...

Comment: ... Daher gibt es überhaupt keine ultimativen Regeln für die Grammatik, das Vokabular und die Aussprache der deutschen Sprache. Das alles ist *de jure* völlig ungeregelt und wird *de facto* ausschließlich durch den tatsächlichen Gebrauch normiert. Daher steht der tatsächliche Gebrauch einer lebenden Sprache wie Deutsch **immer** über allen Regeln, die Germanisten aus diesem tatsächlichen Gebrauch herausdestillieren und in Bücher gießen.

Comment: Das ist eine Frage-Antwort Seite mit dem Schwerpunkt auf autoritative Antworten. Wortkreationen und Meinungen helfen nicht unbedingt weiter.

Comment: Willst du damit andeuten, dass es falsch wäre, Wörter wie »Gitarrensaite«, »Windelbox« oder »Papierbuch« zu verwenden? Oder worauf genau willst du hinaus? Ich verstehe ehrlich gesagt die genaue Intention deiner vielen Kommentare nicht.

Comment: Ich will sagen daß wir klarmachen was Meinungen sind und was Sprachgebrauch a la Duden und DWDS ist. Das geht aus Deinen Antworten oft nicht hervor. Und du hast ein Problem, Fehler zu korrigieren.

Comment: @a_donda: Seit 25 Jahren falsch: *"daß".* Welche Fehler habe ich nicht korrigiert? Wenn du Fehler findest, darfst du sie gerne selber korrigieren. Deine Reputation berechtigt dich dazu. Da musst du keine langen Kommentare schreiben. Stelle bitte einfach richt, was falsch ist. Einfach auf "edit" klicken und loslegen.

Comment: @a_donda: Wenn du Fehler in meinen Antworten findest (und davon habe ich zweifellos viele gemacht), bitte ich höflichst um Korrektur. Wenn du findest, dass eine meiner einer Antworten schlecht oder gar falsch wäre, kannst du sie gerne abwerten (wenn sie falsch ist sollst du das sogar!) und selbst eine eigene Antwort schreiben, die besser ist. So funktioniert Stackexchange. Mach's einfach selber besser anstatt andere für deren Stil zu kritisieren. Nörgle nicht herum sondern versuche ein besseres Vorbild zu sein.

Answer (score 1):

The translator's version is grammatically correct, but seems rather awkward in that it puts so many words between *Ebooks* and *Papier*, seeing as those are the things that are being compared here. Also, the translator version substitutes the specific meaning "environmental(ly) friendly* for the rather meaningless "better"/*besser*. But Carsten S's comment is correct in that the verb must come right after the adverbial phrase if that's how you're starting the sentence. There is, in fact, only one clause here; *Meiner Meinung nach* and *trotzdem* are just adverbial phrases, not subclauses, since they don't contain verbs. I think either one could reasonably placed in the first position depending on what you're trying to emphasize, but putting *Meiner Meinung nach* first helps keep the rest of the elements connected. So I think

> *Meiner Meinung nach sind E-Books trotzdem umweltfreundlicher als Papier.*

is probably the best version.

Side note: It seems unusual to see the preposition *nach* after the phrase it's connected to, technically making it a postposition. Apparently it's allowed in the sense "according to", but not in any of its other senses.

Comment: Warum sollte ein Komma nach *"Meiner Meinung nach"* stehen? Ich hab's weggemacht.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast:  Danke. Ich habe vergessen, es zu entfernen, als ich den Satz aus dem Original kopiert habe.